# JAR run from terminal stops running after a couple hours

Tags: terminal, jar, executable-jar, discord-jda

I have a Discord bot that I have only recently started running from terminal. It runs fine when running it in IntelliJ for hours or even days (yes I know waste of resources), but I have noticed that when running it in terminal now it stops after a few hours and I don't know why.

Running it with java -jar *file*

Comment: An unknown jar, containing unknown code, running on an unspecified OS, exits after a certain time with an unknown exit code and error message. Based on that information, the most specific conclusion that we can come to, is that there must be a problem somewhere.

Comment: OK, maybe there was a little bit too much snark in my comment, and I apologize for that, but the fact remains that with the information that you have provided, we will not be able to help you. Do you at least get an error message in your terminal? Does the command complete successfully? Or does it exit with an exit code != 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I was running code that looked for an external file. When running in IntelliJ it naturally ran it from the folder it existed in, but in the terminal I was running it with the full location, rather than changing directory to that folder first. So then when calling to look for X.file, it was just looking in the C drive rather than the folder it existed in.